# C# linq how to get property from predicate list when condition is met

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the following linq query

```
var usersToNotify = trainingUsers.Where(x => delegatesToBeReminded.Any(d => d.UserGuid == x.UserGuid))
                                 .Select(x => new RecipientDetail
                                 {
                                     FullName = x.FullName,
                                     Email = x.Email,
// get property from delegatesToBeReminded
                                 })
                                 .ToList();
```

In the example above, i have trainingusers and delegatesToBeReminded list. i want to retrieve the matching record found in trainingusers and create custom type, with fullname, email from trainingusers and additional property from delegatesTobeReminded.

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Can i use something like this?

```
            var x = from tu in trainingUsers
                    join d in delegatesToBeReminded on tu.UserGuid equals d.UserGuid
                    select new RecipientDetail
                    {
                        FullName = tu.FullName,
                        Email = tu.Email,
                        Session = d.Session
                    };
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you would benefit more from a `Join` than a `Where`?

Comment: I have updated with my solution. Is this the proper way?

Comment: You just added "*Can i use something like this*", well, did you try it?

Comment: yes have just added it. Want to know if this is the right way.

Comment: If it works, then it is the right way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would be to use a join, as you suggested:

```
trainingUsers.Join(
    delegatesToBeReminded,
    user => user.UserGuid,
    delegateToBeReminded => delegateToBeReminded.UserGuid,
    (user, delegateToBeReminded) => new RecipientDetail
    {
        FullName = user.FullName,
        Email = user.Email,
        Delegate = delegateToBeReminded,
    });
```

(Or you can write the equivalent in linq query syntax, as you did).

Another way is to rewrite this in linq query syntax, using `let`:

```
from user in trainingUsers
let delegateToBeReminded = delegatesToBeReminded.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UserGuid == user.UserGuid)
where delegateToBeReminded != null
select new RecipientDetail
{
    FullName = user.FullName,
    Email = user.Email,
    Delegate = delegateToBeReminded,
}
```

**Note** that these differ depending on what happens if there is more than one delegate for a particular user. The first creates a new `RecipientDetail` object for each user/delegate pair; the second creates a `RecipientDetail` object per user, and picks the first delegate.

Comment: thats great. Thank you

Comment: @MukilDeepthi Added more detail. You need to consider what should happen if there is more than one delegate for a given UserGuid.

Comment: thanks. I will go with join as there wont be multiple user with same userguid.